# Ascending Order Bubble sort java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5 at wst2.calc(wst2.java:18)

Tags: java, for-loop, bubble-sort

This is the program that I have made and I even did a proper for loop starting from 0 to 4  as 5 numbers need to be sorted , Still getting  arrayindexoutofboundsexception.

```
import java.util.*; class wst2 {
    public static void calc()
    {
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        int i,j , temp;
        int a[]=new int [5];
        for(i=0;i<=4;i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter 5 numbers");
            a[i]=sc.nextInt();
        }
        for(i=0;i<=4;i++)
        {
            for(j=i;j<=4-i;j++)
            { 
                if(a[j] > a[j+1])
                {
                    temp=a[j];
                    a[j]=a[j+1];
                    a[j+1]=temp;
                }
            }
        }
        for(i=0;i<=4;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(a[i]);
        }
    } }
```

Comment: you loop until `j<=4` but access the element `a[j+1]`. Now you are accessing the element at index 5 in your last iteration, which causes your error.

Comment: So which line should be changed?

Comment: instead of using `4` as a fixed loop determination value, you could just loop until `i<a.length-1` for your sorting.

Comment: well the length is 5 , so 5-1 will give 4 anyway . How is it going to help?

Comment: Here's an example basically verbatim of what you're trying to do:  http://crunchify.com/java-bubble-sort-algorithm-ascending-order-sample/

Change your <= to < in your for loops

Comment: @rockz3r because i am Not using `<=` instead it says  `<`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This statement `int a[]=new int [5];` defines an array with length of 5.
With an array of length 5, you can access elements with indices form **0** to **4** (`{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}`).
But at this line

```
a[j]=a[j+1];
```

in a possible and particular condition (`j = 4` and `i = 0`), you are trying to access to the `a[4+1]` (means `a[5]`) which is not allowed.